# Regarding the [garrys-mod] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I'm not actually sure why [garrys-mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/garrys-mod) was created. There don't seem to be any experts on it, and some questions with it don't even seem to be related to the game.

Comment: Don´t forget Garry Newman :p

Comment: The tag seems fine as long as it the questions are about the API within Garry's Mod.  I think the wiki entry should be clarified.